# oxwall OW_EventManager bind and trigger

Tags: php, oxwall

I'm using [`oxwall`](https://www.oxwall.com/) and I want to know how `EventManager` works on this platform for registering new methods on specific events with a simple example for triggering and binding an event to a process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for triggering and binding an event to a process. My formatting sucks a bit...

Say you are creating a plugin for creating user account.

```
/**
* Method to save user
*/
public function saveUser( $username, $password, $email, $accountType )
{
    $userService = BOL_UserService::getInstance();
    $user = $userService->createUser( $username, $password, $email, $accountType );

    //Set new event parameters
    $event = new OW_Event('plugin_key_custom_event_name', array(
        'userDto' => $user
    ));
    //Trigger an event for after registering user
    OW::getEventManager()->trigger($event );
}
```

**Bind Event to Listener**

You should do this part from your event handler class or from your plugin init.php file.

```
/**
*
* Bind Event
*/
class PLUGINKEY_CLASS_EventHandler
{
    public function sendUserWelcome( OW_Event $e )
    {
         $params = $e->getParams();
         $user = $params['userDto'];

         BOL_UserService::getInstance()->sendWellcomeLetter($user);         
    }

    public function init()
    {
        //bind sendUserWelcome() method to 'plugin_key_custom_event_name' event
        OW::getEventManager()->bind('plugin_key_custom_event_name', array($this, 'sendUserWelcome'));
    }
}
```

Finally, you can initialize the event handler from your init.php file.

```
$eventHandler = new PLUGINKEY_CLASS_EventHandler();
$eventHandler->init();
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at the tutorial I tried to put up [here](https://www.eobasi.com/implementing-oxwall-ow_eventmanager-class/)